# Bootstrap and CSS positioning of a toggle

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie in html programming and hope you will be able to help me without qualifying my question as a 'stupid' one :)

I am using the bootstrap toggle javascript and I am struggling to understand why my elements are overlapping eachother (as shown in the picture below).

I (naively) thought that having a container class 'lorem' would help. It looks like my 'top' property of the lorem class that I set to 50px is simply not considered. What did I make wrong?

I hope my question is legible and will be helpful to other readers.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

this is my css file :

```
#tag_domoos_title{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 150%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 90px;
    color:blue;
    z-index:10;
    font-weight: 900;
}

#tag_update{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 90px;
    color:blue;
}

#datetime{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 90px;
    color:blue;
}

#tag_sunrise_sunset{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
}

#tag_weather_temperature{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 145px;
    right: 15px;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 900;
}

#current_weather_conditions_title{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 95%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
    left: 10px;
    color:blue;
    font-weight: 900;
}

#current_weather_forecast_title{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 95%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 10px;
    color:blue;
    font-weight: 900;
}

#tag_weather_condition{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#tag_additional_weather_information{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 100px;
}

#meteo_forecast{
    font-family:Arial;  
    font-size: 100%;
    float:left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    height:434px;
    width:870px;
    top:200px;
    position: relative;
}

#meteo_forecast_day1{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 215px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#meteo_forecast_day2{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 285px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#meteo_forecast_day3{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 355px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#meteo_forecast_temperature_day1{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 215px;
    right: 5px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_temperature_day2{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 285px;
    right: 5px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_temperature_day3{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 355px;
    right: 5px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_condition_day1{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 235px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_condition_day2{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 305px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_condition_day3{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 375px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
}

#domoos_logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
}

#lorem{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 10px;
    height: auto;
}

#footer
{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 40%;
    clear: both;
    border: 1px groove #aaaaaa;
    background: blue;
    color: White;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

#hyperlinks_mobile
{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
}

ul {
  background: #bbb;
}
li, [class*="grid"] > * {
  background: #ccc;
}
header, footer {
  background: #ddd;
}
body {
    background-color:#ddd;
}
```

this is my html code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Domoos mobile</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle_mobile.css"/>
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/date_time.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Global variables
    var AutoScript = false;
    var ValueCheck = -1;
    </script>
    <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./css/bootstrap-toggle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./css/style_thermostat.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="./js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/bootstrap-toggle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="banner" id="header" role="banner">
        <div id="domoos_logo"><img src="assets/icons/logo_Domoos_lab.png" alt="" style="width:75px;height:54px;"></div>
        <div id="tag_domoos_title">Domoos mobile</div>
        <div id="datetime">
            <script type="text/javascript">window.onload = getTimeDate('datetime');</script>
        </div>
        <div id="tag_sunrise_sunset"><p><img src="assets/icons/sun_icon.png" alt="" width="14" height="14">&#8593; 06:25 &#8595; 20:33</p></div>
    </header>

    <div class="lorem">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="SwitchOnOffAll('on')">Tout allumer</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="SwitchOnOffAll('off')">Tout &#233;teindre</button>
    </div>

            <label>
            <span class="label label-primary">chk01 - Chambre 1 [A]</span>
            <input id="chk01" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-toggle="toggle" data-height="16">
            </label>

            <label>
            <span class="label label-primary">chk02 - Chambre 2 [B]</span>
            <input id="chk02" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-toggle="toggle" data-height="16">
            </label>

            <label>
            <span class="label label-primary">chk03 - Chambre 3 [N]</span>
            <input id="chk03" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-toggle="toggle" data-height="16">
            </label>

            <label>
            <span class="label label-primary">chk04 - Salle de bains (Lavabo) [C]</span>
            <input id="chk04" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-toggle="toggle" data-height="16">
            </label>

            <label>
            <span class="label label-primary">chk05 - Salle de bains (Baignoire) [D]</span>
            <input id="chk05" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-toggle="toggle" data-height="16">
            </label>

            <label>
            <span class="label label-primary">chk06 - Lumi&#232;re WC [Z]</span>
            <input id="chk06" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-toggle="toggle" data-height="16">
            </label>
        </div>
        <input id="lab01" type="text" name="country" class="resizedTextbox" value="20" readonly>
        <a href="#" class="myButton" onclick="TemperatureControl('lab01','decrease')"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="myButton" onclick="TemperatureControl('lab01','increase')"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
        </p>
        <p>
        <input id="lab02" type="text" name="country" class="resizedTextbox" value="20" readonly>
        <a href="#" class="myButton" onclick="TemperatureControl('lab02','decrease')"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="myButton" onclick="TemperatureControl('lab02','increase')"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
        </p>
        <p>
        <input id="lab03" type="text" name="country" class="resizedTextbox" value="20" readonly>
        <a href="#" class="myButton" onclick="TemperatureControl('lab03','decrease')"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="myButton" onclick="TemperatureControl('lab03','increase')"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
        <progress id="prg01" value="10" max="100"></progress>
        </p>
        <div class="footer" id="footer">Domoos web mobile version 0.0</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `#lorem` selects an element with the _id_ `lorem`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using `position:absolute` ?

Comment: It should be noted in the context of OP being a newbie that **`id` values must be unique per document**. Each given value can only be applied to a maximum of one element per document. ***Furthermore, it is strongly advisable to make use of classes and not ids in CSS.***